# Applying two filters at once with FFMPEG -filter_complex and -vf

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, overlay, slowmotion

I have need to make a slowmotion video with overlay png.
Source video is 240fps and h265 (HEVC)
I want to make a 24fps video with

```
-vf "setpts=(10/1)*PTS"
```

Overlay .png image with

```
 -filter_complex "overlay=10:10"
```

My code:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -r 24 -filter_complex "overlay=10:10" -vf "setpts=(8/1)*PTS" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

But it says that they cannot used together.
I read answers for similar questions, but I can't apply answers to my problem...

Answer (score 3):

Use

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -i watermark.png -filter_complex "[0]setpts=PTS*10,fps=24[v];[v][1]overlay=10:10" -c:v libx264 -preset ultrafast -crf 26 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

If you're filtering multiple streams in some sequence, then all filters need to be specified within a single filter_complex. In this case, we first slow down the video, and then overlay the watermark on it.

Comment: Please add an explanation.